# Memory efficient LDA training using gensim library

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Today I just started writing an script which trains LDA models on large corpora (minimum 30M sentences) using gensim library.
Here is the current code that I am using:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities, matutils

def train_model(fname):
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open(fname))
    print "DOC2BOW"
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split()) for line in open(fname)]

    print "running LDA"
    lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, asses=1)
```

running this script on a small corpus (2M sentences) I realized that it needs about 7GB of RAM.
And when I try to run it on the larger corpora, it fails because of the memory issue.
The problem is obviously due to the fact that I am loading the corpus using this command:

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split()) for line in open(fname)]
```

But, I think there is no other way because I would need it for calling the LdaModel() method:

```
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, asses=1)
```

I searched for a solution to this problem but I could not find anything helpful.
I would imagine that it should be a common problem since we mostly train the models on very large corpora (usually wikipedia documents). So, it should be already a solution for it.

Any ideas about this issue and the solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider wrapping your `corpus` up as an iterable and passing that instead of a list (a generator will not work).

From [the tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_corpora_and_vector_spaces.html#corpus-streaming-tutorial):

```
class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
       for line in open(fname):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split())

corpus = MyCorpus()
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, 
                                      id2word=dictionary,
                                      num_topics=100,
                                      update_every=1,
                                      chunksize=10000,
                                      passes=1)
```

Additionally, Gensim has several different corpus formats readily available, which can be found in the [API reference](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/apiref.html).  You might consider using `TextCorpus`, which should fit your format nicely already:

```
corpus = gensim.corpora.TextCorpus(fname)
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, 
                                      id2word=corpus.dictionary, # TextCorpus can build the dictionary for you
                                      num_topics=100,
                                      update_every=1,
                                      chunksize=10000,
                                      passes=1)
```

Comment: The correct link to the relevant tutorial is now: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_corpora_and_vector_spaces.html#corpus-streaming-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, @Carsten!